# JS streaming from binary file

Tags: javascript, streaming, mouse

So I know that javascript libraries like SoundManager2 are able to "stream" music to a client. With "stream" I am talking about

1) File is stored on a server and fetched by the application from user request
2) File is "buffered" like a video
3) File then plays for the user in a kind of player

To my understanding this is no problem for a MP3 file which is basically just a (complex) file with some headers and basically binary information. How would one go about doing this kind of streaming for binary file that contains for example information about a mouse position.

My goal is to create a possibility to save mouse movement in a file and then play it back as a stream to other users and offer possibility to go back and forth within the mouse recording.

Comment: You could start by creating your own "text based" file format. I'd suggest JSON format with an array of objects. In each object,
keys being milliseconds from start & value being {x: <xvalue>,y : <yvalue>}

Answer (score 0):

I would make a serverside script that is able to chop up the file you are talking about.

Then, you would call it like

```
.../file.php?name=mousepositions.json&start=34&length=10
```

Where you would receive parts 34-43. You can then show those parts, and in the meanwhile fetch the next part

```
.../file.php?name=mousepositions.json&start=44&length=10
```

On the client, you can use the received parts to fill an array (or Object) so that you know which parts you already have and which you are missing. Then, when a user is seeking, you can fetch from the local Object/Array and only fetch those parts that are missing.